# Flash CC, AS3 - textfield value reset after keyframe

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield

I found what seems to be a strange bug in Flash CC. It never been happening in previous versions of Flash and it's a fairly major thing so I'm surprised I couldn't find any information about it online...

I have a MovieClip with a TextField. Somewhere in the middle of the timeline there is a keyframe where textfield should change it's IU properties (but it's name remains the same). 
In the beginning of the movieclip I'm assigning a value to the textfield.text and let it run. The text changes successfully but when it gets to the keyframe it's value resets to what it is originally built in flash. Even if the value was empty it'll remove the text...

It used to work in previous versions of Flash as long as the TF instance was exist continuously but doesn't seem to be working anymore. 
Does anyone else had this problem and found a solution?

A simple example screenshot of a timeline and AS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Flash treats a keyframe as a change of text property too. So you need to repeat tf.text="blahblah';  along or you can put this textfield inside a movieclip and keyframe it instead of the textfield (mc.tf.text="blahblah";)